# Integrate right to left text label expression with fields in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, labeling, internationalization, unicodedecodeerror

I try to insert this label expression in ArcGIS 10.3 in the layer properties. The expression has field from the attribute table and some text(right to left orientation) that i added (it isn't in some filed of the attribute table):

```
'אאא ' + [Muni_Heb]
```

I also tried to add 'u' to this expression:

```
u'אאא ' + [Muni_Heb]
```

[image]

but i get an error:

[image]

I don't understand what my mistake is.

Comment: Your solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte

Comment: try `u"\u03C7" + [Muni_Heb]`