# Left to right labels disappearing in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, arcgis-10.3, hebrew

I try to write this word 'אזוה"ת' (Left to right label) with the value from field "nam" in the Label Expression with no success (the label expression dissapear):

```
u'אזוה"ת ' + [nam]
```

[image]

the wanted result should be: אזוה"ת כפר קאסם

this is my field details:

[image]
[image]

when I wrote the expression this way:

```
u'אזוהת ' + [nam]
```

it works but not as I need (need to add " Apostrophes sign):

[image]

I know I can create another field with the value 'אזוה"ת' , but i need the solution with the way I wrote above

I also read [Integrate right to left text label expression with fields in ArcGIS 10.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265324/integrate-right-to-left-text-label-expression-with-fields-in-arcgis-10-3)  and didn't found any answer.

Comment: I think the issue is down to how it is interpreting " in your text, normally a backslash is used in python as an escape character, but it did not work. This [page](https://www.webforefront.com/django/pythonbasics-text.html) might give a hint to the source of the problem, they say support is better for unicode characters in Python 3, ArcMap uses python 2.7? Unless someone comes forward with a solution I would be contacting ESRI to see if they have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The reason for disappearing label is the use of double quotes in between your label
2. I created a test field with double quotes and in the label expression added the desired values using **" "**
3. If you want to add double quotes use ''(Sigle quotes twice) and check the result again
4. **"u'אזוהת '"**+[nam]
5. Another possible reason could be the missing quotes in the expression to be considered as a string input

[image]